# Cross-Platform AppData dir with Spring and Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, cross-platform

I develop an application which will be used on Windows and Mac OS. I use H2 db there. I want to store my db files in AppData dir. Like this:

**application.properties:**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:${APP_DATA}/data/keywords
```

`APP_DATA` should be `${user.home}/AppData/Roaming/` for **Windows** and `${user.home}/Library/Application Support` for **Mac**.

I thought about having two Maven profiles for both Windows and Mac (I will ship them separately anyway) and using maven resources plugin filtering, in this way:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:${user.home}${suffix}
```

The problem is, I can't filter only `suffix` and leave `user.home` untouched. Now as a result I get `C:\\Users\\Denis/AppData/Roaming/Keywords` after the Maven build which is incorrect as I need to `user.home` proceed on user's machine.

For now I see only solution to move `suffix` to separate file, then exclude `application.properties` from resources plugin and then somehow intregate first into second. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I need is to escape `${user.home}` with backslash `\`:

**application.properties**

```
APP_DATA=\${user.home}${app.data.dir}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<properties>
    <app.data.dir>/AppData/Roaming/</app.data.dir>
</properties>
```

For me that's all, but it may be also needed to add this ([docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/escape-filtering.html)):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <escapeString>\</escapeString>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```